# Apache Kafka Consumer - Broker host resolution between Java Client vs. rest of the Clients

Tags: java, apache-kafka

There is a scenario where I would be required to connect to external kafka and consume data for further processing. Is there a fundamental difference between kafka python client vs. Java clients in the way they are implemented?

Python Client with the same host connects to broker and consumes over TLS but both Kafka console consumer or any java based clients establishes connection to broker (successfuly does SSL Handshake) but further fails as the client is not able to connect and subscribe.

I am aware of listeners and advertised listeners, but python kafka is able to establish connection to broker and consume fine which confuses me.

Can anyone elaborate on how different the clients are from each other?

Answer (score 0):

The Kafka TCP protocol is the same for all clients.

Java, however, might require JKS files in addition to TLS certificates.

Non Java clients cannot use JKS files, however. If you're using the Confluent Python client, then it'll use librdkafka, which is also implemented by `kcat` CLI, which you could also test with rather than builtin Kafka tools